# Java: Why implement an interface and its superinterface?

Tags: java, inheritance, interface, extends, implements

I understand the term *superinterface* can be ambiguous. Let me explain.

- Interface `AB` extends interfaces `A` and `B`.
- `A` and `B` don't extend anything else.

Now, we have abstract class `X` implementing both `AB` and `A`.

Why is this necessary? Isn't it enough for abstract class `X` just to implement `AB`?

Comment: Yes, that is sufficient. You can add `[implements] A, B` for explicitness.

Comment: Maybe some legacy code stayed in there, as it originally only implemented `A`? Or maybe for documentation clarity? Functionally, it doesn't change a thing and the `A` part could be removed.

Comment: It most likely only does implement the implement `AB`, the JavaDoc tool shows the entire relationship regardless of how the programmer chooses to specify it.

Comment: *Right now* AB extends A and B, but that may change. If you "simplify" the interfaces implemented, you may lose capturing the original intention.

Comment: Usually interfaces extending other interface(s) is a sign of over engineering.